# How can I find a good school to learn Japanese in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, study, japanese-language

So I'm trying to live in Tokyo, and would like to learn japanese. I'm looking for an immersion school that will teach me Japanese starting from the basics to intermediate level (JPTL4-JPTL2).

I used to live in a city which had tons of schools teaching English, but most were very sketchy and only wanted to turn a profit, even hiring non-english speakers. I don't want to end up in the japanese version of one of those.

My Question is... How can I tell which school is good for this?

Is there a review site that reviews these school? Can anyone recommend a good one?

Comment: Maybe this fits better at japanese.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't find out anything on-line, just take some time when you get to Tokyo. Find the addresses of some schools and actually go there and hang around outside, then ask some of the students for their opinions as they come out for a break.

I did this when I learned Spanish in Antigua (Guatemala) which is full of Spanish schools.

Comment: Your advice seems like the most sound advice so far.